# How to change string to Integers in python

Tags: python, list

Trying to remove single quotes from around numbers. I'm working with third paty data that's not well typed.

```
lst =  [ ('text','2','3','4'), ('text2','4','5','6') ]
y=  [map(int,i) for i in zip(*lst)[1:]] 

d = zip(*list)[0]
print d
c= zip(*y)
print c

dd = zip(d,c)
print dd
```

this is what the out is:

```
('text', 'text2')
[(2, 3, 4), (4, 5, 6)]
[('text', (2, 3, 4)), ('text2', (4, 5, 6))]
```

How Do I get:

```
dd =  [ ('text',2,3,4), ('text2',4,5,6) ]
```

EDIT:
If list is sometimes this: `[ ['text','2','3','4'], ['text2','4','5','6'] ]`, then what do i do? Another problem is integer as '3,400'.

New Lst example:

```
  lst =  [ ('text','2','3','4'), ('text2','4','5,000','6,500') ]
```

Need:

```
 [ ('text',2,3,4), ('text2',4,5000,6500) ]
```

Comment: What is `3,400'` supposed to mean? `3`, `3400` or `3.4` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print [(text, int(a), int(b), int(c)) for (text, a, b, c) in lst]
```

Comment: damn it, I thought it was harder.

Comment: if list is sometimes this: lst =  [ ['text','2','3','4'], ['text2','4','5','6'] ]. then would do i do?

Comment: @user428862: It doesn't matter what kind the sequence is, just the number of items in it is important. So you use the same code.

Comment: @user428862: if you have commas in the numbers, then you can change the `int(a)` type calls to `int(a.replace(',',''))`. That's assuming that 3,333 means 3333 in your numbers.

Comment: @user428862: `print [(text, int(a), int(b.replace(',','')), int(c.replace(',',''))) for (text, a, b, c) in lst]`

Answer (score 2):

Jochen's answer is the right thing for your specific case.

If, for some reason, you need to take the list of types as a parameter you can do something like this:

```
>>> lst =  [ ('text','2','3','4'), ('text2','4','5','6') ]

>>> def map_rows(types, rows):
...     return [tuple(f(x) for f, x in zip(types, row)) for row in rows]

>>> map_rows((str, int, int, int), lst)
[('text', 2, 3, 4), ('text2', 4, 5, 6)]
```

The `map_rows` defined above is sort of a cousin of the standard `map` function. Note that "types" is really a sequence of callables that "convert" the value in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [('text','2','3','4'), ('text2','4','5','6')]
dd = []
for t in lst:
    new_tuple = []
    for i in t:
        try:
            new_tuple.append(int(i))
        except ValueError:
            new_tuple.append(i)
    dd.append(tuple(new_tuple))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst =  [ ('text','2','3','4'), ('text2','4','5','6') ]

new_lst = []

for tup in lst:
    tmp = []
    for index, item in enumerate(tup):
        if index != 0:
            tmp.append(int(item))
        else:
            tmp.append(item)
    new_lst.append(tuple(tmp))

print new_lst
```

This is probably not the pythonic way of doing it :)